# Preload image before changing src of img tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been using the following code to change an img src.

```
$('#wrapperHeaderImage img').attr("src", '<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/images/char2.png');
```

However when the src is changed it will reload the image each time.

I then tried to preload the image by using a css trick on an already existing div then waiting for the page to completely load.

```
#something { background: url('imgUrl') no-repeat -9999px -9999px; }
```

However it just reloaded the image when I changed the src to the same url as in the css.

The images are being faded in and out, I am not sure if that changes anything.

Thanks.

Comment: How about having many image elements with different sources and making the one you want visible and rest hidden

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery

Comment: Thanks user568109... Such a simple solution and it completely missed it.

Comment: @user568109 That will increase the amount of HTTP requests though.